# What values should I return if I don't want to implement selections in a QAbstractItemView?

Tags: c++, qt

Considering a *normal* `Model` class defined by just implementing pure functions from `QAbstractItemModel`.

I have to display the model with a pie chart (like in [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-chart-pieview-cpp.html)) and I thought of derive from `QAbstractItemView` and just reimplement its protected slots.

The fact is that `QAbstractItemView` force me to implement other pure virtual functions:

```
virtual QModelIndex moveCursor(CursorAction, Qt::KeyboardModifiers);
virtual int horizontalOffset() const;
virtual int verticalOffset() const;
virtual bool isIndexHidden(const QModelIndex&) const;
virtual void setSelection(const QRect&, QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags);
virtual QRegion visualRegionForSelection(const QItemSelection&) const;
virtual QRect visualRect (const QModelIndex&) const;
virtual void scrollTo(const QModelIndex&, ScrollHint);
virtual QModelIndex indexAt(const QPoint&) const;
```

Most of this functions are useless in my case and as of right now I am returning `0`, default values (for example `return QRect();`) or invalid values (for example `return QModelIndex()`).

My question is: what are these functions supposed to be used for (yes I [RTFM](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qabstractitemview.html) but it barely tells you what values you should return)? Can I just ignore them, the way I am doing, and not expect repercussions?

Comment: Without guarantee,  but since this is a view, I'd say: WYSIWYG. In other words, if your program works correctly, it is most unlikely that there are any unexpected repercussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're the user of your own view, it's entirely up to you. If you don't feel like having a fully functional view, it's OK. The functions are used for selection and keyboard/mouse interaction with the items in the view. It's fine not to provide that functionality if you don't need it.

In many of read-only views that don't support interaction other than perhaps scrolling, deriving from a `QAbstractItemView` is rather pointless. I have an internal class I use instead. IMHO, Qt should further split the QAbstractItemView class so that interaction-free views would use something simpler.

You may be reassured by the fact that Qt itself provides lots of views that don't implement `QAbstractItemView`. Like every QML view :)

The minimum requirement for a "view" is that it derives from `QObject`. You can have non-gui "views" after all, that consume data from some model. Proxy models are such: they are gui-less views that attach to a model, and at the same time are a model themselves. To the source model, a proxy is like a view. To the user view, a proxy is like a model.